# How to compute the disk space usage of a row in a mysql innodb table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an application that inserts many rows in a specific innodb table and I don't know how to compute the disk space needed in the future.

So given a mysql innodb table structure, how can I compute the disk space cost of a row?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html

Comment: You can't. Reason: you haven't shown us the table definition and if you have variable-length columns (varchars, texts, blobs) - you can't determine what's the average length with accuracy. Your best bet is to compute the average length using the data you have now. If you get to the point where you can fill a few hundred gigs, you'll have so many other problems and none of those will be disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TINYINT consumes 1 byte, INT: 4 bytes, BIGINT: 8 bytes, TEXT/BLOB/VARCHAR/VARBINARY: 2+ average number of *bytes*, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP: 5 bytes, CHAR takes the full length, etc.
2. Add those up, based on the columns in the table.
3. Multiple by 3 (for overhead, indexes, BTree structure, wasted space, etc, etc).  This will give you a *crude estimate* of the disk space for an InnoDB row.

Caveats:

- The result could be high or low, but it is a simple first guess.
- A table will take a minimum of 16KB.
- An excessive number of secondary indexes will lead to more space consumed.
- Lots of TEXTs/BLOBs can lead to off-record storage that is likely to exceed the forumla.
- At some point during the growth of a table, the allocation unit switches from 16KB to 8MB, thereby leading to disturbing jumps in the size.
- ROW_FORMAT makes some difference.  (But COMPRESSED is unlikely to shrink the table by more than 2x.)
- Look for ways to shrink UUIDs, IP addresses, etc, to save space.
- Don't use utf8 for ascii-only CHAR() strings (country_code, hex, etc).